# Python - Cannot access Requests Json list

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am really struggling with a search of a dict in python.  What I do is call an external API using the Requests package.

```
response = requests.get(apiurl + vnendpoint + '?page=1&per_page=0&sort=id&api_key=' + apikey)

records = response.json()
```

This works fine and returns the following dict:

```
{u'pagination': {u'per_page': 0, u'total': 187, u'page': 1}, u'data': [{u'status': u'Inactive', u'name': u'access-a37', id': u'2', u'peripheral':...
```

The problem is, I now want to search the `data` object, which is a list inside the original JSON, for an ID which may or may not be there.

```
x = "1"
if x in records:
    print("add")
```

This is the part I cannot get past.  It always returns a false response, but I know the ID is there.

Am I missing something really straight forward here?

Thanks

Comment: You are searching inside the outer `dict` not the list. You have to access the list first. Then, you will need to check the `id` field in the dicts I side that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `if x in records:` you're checking if the value of x (`"1"`) itself is in `records`. It's not. According to your question, what is in `records['data']` is a dictionary containing an item called `id` with the value `"1"`. Python doesn't know it needs to look into `id` for you.

You have two options:

1. Go over every item in the list, access its `id` item and compare it to `x`.
2. Build a dictionary mapping the `id` item to the actual data and use that for looking up `x`.

Code samples:

```
for i in records['data']:
  if i['id'] == x:
    print('found', x)

# or

d = {}
for i in records['data']:
  d[i['id']] = i
if x in d:
  print('found', x)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, get the data object from records

```
myData=records['data']
```

Then search for your id in myData

```
x = 1
myDict = dict()
for dictionnary in myData:
      if ( dictionnary['id'] == x ):
         print ('found',x)
         myDict = dictionnary
         break
```